# Android 11 File Read/Write Permission issue in Java Code

Tags: android, file-read

I am trying to access a file `/mnt/sdcard/test.txt` in Android App through Java code `File file = new File(path + "/test.txt");`. When I check file existence through `file.exists()`, it returns false in Android 11. **But the same source code works fine till Android 10.**

In AndroidManisfest.xml I have given all below permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

Comment: Please go through [Scoped storage enforcement](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#scoped-storage)

Comment: Try with Realtime Permission. it would work. There Are bunches of code sample to do this!

Comment: Your app did not put that file there. And you did not tell who did it.

Comment: I have tried with /sdcard/test.txt path instead of /mnt//sdcard/test.txt. It is working fine.                           File file = new File("/sdcard/test.txt");
if(file.exists())
            Log.i("Test", "File Exists");
        else
            Log.i("Test", "File Not Exists");

Comment: @ShivBuyya you got the solution for your question ?
If yes then give the solution i am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with `/sdcard/test.txt` path instead of `/mnt//sdcard/test.txt`. It is working fine.

Tested with below code, it prints File Exists:

```
 File file = new File("/sdcard/test.txt");
 if(file.exists())
     Log.i("Test", "File Exists");
 else 
     Log.i("Test", "File Not Exists");
```